# Object Reference Error in Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexSummary.get_NumberOfDocuments()

Tags: solr

I am running Solr 5.5.4.  When I open the index manager, I see a bunch of errors in the Sitecore log file of the following:

```
5664 13:40:46 ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexSummary.get_NumberOfDocuments()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client.Forms.IndexingManagerWizard.BuildIndexCheckbox(String name, String header, ListString selected, ListString indexMap)
```

Our Solr solution is using zookeeper and a Solr Cloud setup.  Does anyone know why that command isn't working?

Comment: What Sitecore version? Can you see any other errors around that in the logs? Do you have documents in your index? Is it crawling ok? Lots of questions for this, please provide some more info so we can help diagnose the issue.

Comment: We are at Sitecore 8.2u3.  No other errors in the log around that time, or related to Solr.  We do have data in our indexes and crawling is ok otherwise.  The only side-effect that I can tell from this error is not seeing the document numbers in the index rebuild dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the #solr Slack channel, someone posted this link about the issue:
https://sitecoresaga.wordpress.com/2017/05/15/sitecore-8-2-exceptions-when-re-index-from-control-panel/

Sitecore has a patch which can hide these exceptions from showing up in the log file.  But, they do not have a fix for returning the document count for SolrCloud setups.

Comment: I can confirm this patch works and solves this issue for 8.2u3 and 8.2u5 in SolrCloud configurations.

Answer (score 2):

We encountered exact the same issue recently due to the wrong Solr core name in the config files. By default, a Solr core is named *"sitecore_master_index"* in the config, but in our case we called it *"our_sitecore_site_master_index"* in Solr. So, I suggest you to make sure that your Solr cores are named consistently between the Sitecore configs and Solr setup itself.

Comment: I am guessing your issue was dealing with a Solr index on a single server and not a Solr Cloud setup since you mention core names and not alias names.  I hate it when the same error happens for different reasons though. Thanks for making mention of it in case others also find this via search in the future.