# SolrCloud and the Indexing Manager not showing statistical information

Tags: solr

We are looking at deploying SolrCloud with our 8.2.5 install. Everything seems to be running OK so far, however I've noticed that the Indexing manager does not load any of the indexing statistical data for a SolrCloud configuration.

Solr with statistics showing (not a solrcloud configuration)
[image: Working Index Manager with Statistics]

Solr without statistics (in a solrcloud configuration)
[image: SolrCloud with no Statistics]
After doing a bit of reflection and request tracing, it appears as though Sitecore is using the SolrNet library and executing a URL like: [solrserver]/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&core=sitecore_master_index to retrieve this information.

With SolrCloud this is not going to work, because the cores will get suffixed with e.g. _shard1_replica1, _shard1_replica2 for 2 node environment.

Has anyone seen a customization to this display to present data back to the user, or have just simply leave it as default?
I would imagine we need to override SolrSearchIndex class and try retrieve these stats on the first replica to atleast achieve the same result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like Sitecore has a patch to hide the exceptions that get thrown in the logs in relation to this but I do not know of a fix yet https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/8469/148

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore mentions 10.x.x.x:8983. You tried to build an index from the `Sitecore Index Manager`. The system seemed to hang or took a very long time to complete indexing. There was an error saying `Unable to connect to Solr` and mentioning an internal IP address (10.x.x.x) and port 8983. Alternatively, you may have seen a Sitecore message saying `ERROR GetSummary has failed due to an exception.`

`This is a known bug in Sitecore.` To get around it:
Generate the index from the Sitecore Content Editor instead of the Index Manager.
Contact Sitecore for a patch file. **This bug is being tracked by Sitecore under the reference number – 355209.**
This situation sometimes arises due to a misconfiguration of the Sitecore 10/Solr connection. See Walkthrough: Setting up SolrCloud, section Configure Sitecore to use SolrCloud, step 3:

If you only access nodes of SolrCloud within a private network, set the `ContentSearch.IndexingManager.DisplayShortStatistic` setting to `true`. This eliminates direct requests to the nodes used to display additional index statistics in the Indexing Manager Wizard.

**So the fix is set the ContentSearch.IndexingManager.DisplayShortStatistic setting to true.**

You can find the config at `App_Config/Sitecore/ContentSearch/Sitecore.ContentSearch.config`